# LightGBM plot_tree() Leaf numbers

Tags: lightgbm

What do the numbers on the LightGBM plot_tree method represent? As an example, I used the Pima Indian Diabettes dataset and then used the plot_tree method to yield the following:
[image]

What do the numbers on the leaf nodes represent?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean leaf numbers like "leaf 1", "leaf 2", ect.

They are just labels that represent each leaf output.

To understand it better, I would suggest checking the following URL:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-gradient-boosting-decision-trees-xgboost-python/

Comment: No, I am not referring to these leaf numbers. The question is about the the floating values after the leaf numbers. Using the graph above as an example, leaf 0 has a value of -0.668. What does -0.668 mean?

Comment: The values should be the "information gain" for each decision. Depending on the settings of the LightGBM, it could also be entropy, Gini impurity, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look it up.

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926340/what-does-the-value-of-leaf-in-the-following-xgboost-model-tree-diagram-means) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395697/what-is-an-intuitive-interpretation-of-the-leaf-values-in-xgboost-base-learners). Note that those values on the leaves are **not** "information gains" as Koorosh Aslansefat suggested.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API description](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.plot_tree.html), It is the **predicted value**.
Actually, It's **residual** on the leaf.
The each residuals are combined to generate the final estimate.

By the way,
There are many articles on Gradient Boosting Decision Tree Algorithm,
but one of the simplest explanations is [here](https://www.coryjmaklin.com/2019-05-17_Machine-Learning-Part-18--Boosting-Algorithms--Gradient-Boosting-In-Python-ef5ae6965be4/).