# Catboost plot_tree understanding

Tags: python, decision-tree, catboost

When plotting a tree from catboost, it shows `val` in leaves; what do these values represent?

I can't find the answer in their official tutorial on plotting, nor are there any such questions answered anywhere that I could find. Like:

1. [LightGBM plot_tree() Leaf numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713364/lightgbm-plot-tree-leaf-numbers)
2. [What' the meaning of "Val" in the visualization of a lightgbm tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57940941/what-the-meaning-of-val-in-the-visualization-of-a-lightgbm-tree)
3. https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues?q=plot_tree

[image: Binary Classification]
[image: MultiClass Classification]

Comment: Just came across this question.  Are [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69470096/what-is-the-scale-of-the-leaf-values-in-a-catboostregressor-tree/71697767#71697767) helpful?

Answer (score 1):

These are values predicted by the tree.
There are more than one value for multi-classification and multi-regression.

Please note that as we do not monitor Stack Overflow very closely, it is better to ask questions at our [Github repo](https://github.com/catboost/catboost).

Comment: Thanks, but what do these values mean for classification?
I have also raised an [issue](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/1389) on github. Which I didn't really understand.