# what does a leaf node mean in XGBRegressor model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I am inspecting the following model:

[image: decision tree plot]

And I realized the `leaf` nodes are not on the same order of magnitude as the input data (.9 vs .09). Does this mean that once a leaf node is chosen it will multiply the input data by that leaf node to get a prediction?

It doens't really seem like that's what's going on, unless somehow the model for `.predict` is different than the model it plots.

[image: test]

testing it out manually gives me something way different. Instead, it seems to nearly predict the same value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the value of 'leaf' in the following xgboost model tree diagram means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926340/what-does-the-value-of-leaf-in-the-following-xgboost-model-tree-diagram-means) (The accepted answer is more helpful than the highest voted answer.)

Comment: @NickODell I was just reading that and, no, actually. the `return` result, is that the raw prediction? if so why don't I get 0.0992... when I run predict on that value? besides, that question is about classification, and I'm talking about regression... maybe the plot_tree from scikit-learn that I'm using doesn't handle the difference well? idk. it sounds much more like the first answer, that the leaf is expressing some probability, but I don't know what that means in a regression case.

Comment: Looking into this a bit further, XGBoost is creating multiple trees. So `plot_tree(xgb, num_trees=0)` shows you the first tree, `plot_tree(xgb, num_trees=1)` shows you the second one, etc. To see the number of trees that XGBoost is fitting, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50426248/how-to-know-the-number-of-tree-created-in-xgboost).

Comment: @NickODell thanks! that makes way more sense now, I wish I could plot the resulting tree instead of investigating them one at a time, I don't know how they're weighted so turns out this does me very little good, but it does make sense that the leaf node is maybe a real prediction then...

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.